# How do I add a list to a table in Clojure?

Tags: list, clojure, functional-programming

This is a model of my list.

```
[ [name age salary] [name age salary] [name age salary] ]
```

Let's say I have a def named "description_list" that contains this list.

How do I iterate through description_list and put it into a table. I tried doing this:

```
(print-table [:Name :Age :Salary] description_list)
```

And that prints out 3 empty rows of a table for me. I need it to actually contain the information from the list. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.  See the [doc for print-table](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/print-table).

> Prints a collection of *maps* in a textual table.

So you need to turn your `descr_list` into a list of maps.  E.g.

```
user=> (let [h [:a :b] 
             d [[1 2][3 4]]] 
         (clojure.pprint/print-table 
            h 
            (map (partial zipmap h) d)))

| :a | :b |
|----+----|
|  1 |  2 |
|  3 |  4 |
```